# Magento 2: Compile-Multi-Tenant "Not Defined"

Tags: magento2, module, command-line, setup-di-compile

My Module reject from Marketplace QA testing. The error they gave was:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class \Fanplayr\SmartAndTargeted\Controller\Index\Index does not exist
```

They also let me know test command they used:

```
php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant 2>&1
```

With my local copies of Magento 2 (both CE and EE) I get an error when trying to do 'multi-tenant' compilation:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "setup:di:compile-multi-tenant" is not defined.
```

Any idea of why Magento 2 would not be allowing me to do a 'multi-tenant' compilation?

Would this 'multi-tenant' compilation give me errors that normal compilation wouldn't?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html try to use `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` `Class \Fanplayr\SmartAndTargeted\Controller\Index\Index` You have to Make Index Folder & then create Index.php file

Answer (score 2):

In Magento versions 2.0.5 and earlier, there is a known issue with the single-tenant compiler; it does not currently compile proxies. Therefore, if you're preparing to deploy to production, you must use the multi-tenant compiler.

The issue was resolved in Magento versions 2.0.6 and later.

That means, If you using higher versions of Magento (>2.0.6) the multi-tenant command will not be available to you. So, Run the single-tenant compiler.

> Run the command as follows (there are no options):

```
magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I have used 2.1.3 version.not working "setup:di:compile-multi-tenant"..any idea why?

Comment: Please read the answer. it is not available for the versions greater than 2.0.6. just run **setup:di:compile** command

Comment: okey..but why??